# How to create layout for profile in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-drawable

How to create layout for profile like this image using imageview and some textview?

[image]

Comment: only ask for technical help...

Comment: Have you trough to implement it? And what sort of problem you got in this process? Now I can answer - you can create it by IDE and your XML knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Do not forget to set sizes you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="someImage" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name:"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Age:"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lives:"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lives"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From:"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put it to drawable folder and set in ImageView android:src="@drawable/some_image"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need for 4 Textview's for your personal data add them to LinearLayout with VERTICAL Orientation. Then add imageview and first LinearLayout to another LinearLayout but with HORIZONTAL Orientation!

hope this helpful you,